# Trouble in executing Python Script from 'Build Step' in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am having issues in executing a Python script from a Jenkins Pipeline. I already have a Jenkins Multi job Pipeline, in which I am introducing an extra Build step which will execute my Python script.

In the 'Build Step' in Jenkins I noticed an option "Execute Python Script" in which I added my Python Script, when I execute the job, it fails at my Python code with a syntax error. Please note that my Python code works well in a local IDE.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can we not execute Python code directly from the Jenkins Build step? Is there any other way I could execute?

[Jenkins Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btOpM.png)
[Error while executing job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu48a.png)

Comment: Apparently you have a syntax error in your Python code, or in the code that tries to execute the Python code. I'm not sure how we can tell you why that is, because you didn't show the code, or the exact error message.

Comment: Which Python version are you using to execute the code in your local IDE, and which Python version is Jenkins using?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Can we directly add the full Python code in this Jenkins 'Post Build' section or should I save the Python code in a folder & give a execute command ?

Comment: I am using Python 3.9

Comment: I don't know that. But what about the Python version that Jenkins is using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148435/jenkins-post-build-python-script-file  My error is similar to this, but I am unable to follow the solution

Comment: Why don't you just include the error you actually get in the question? Instead of referring to a "similar" error. And which Python version is used by Jenkins?

Comment: Included the screenshot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297859/double-asterisks-error-invalid-syntax

Comment: For future questions, please include code and error messages as text, not as links to screenshots.